# Understanding Character array initialization and data storing

Tags: c++, arrays, char, reinterpret-cast

I am trying to understand how character arrays are initialized and how are the data stored.

I did a test and this is how it goes

```
struct test
{
    char one  [2];
    char two  [2];
    char three[2];
};

test * testptr;

char testchar[] = "hello";

testptr = reinterpret_cast<test*>(testchar);

cout << testptr->one << endl;
cout << testptr->two << endl;
cout << testptr->three << endl;
```

I was expecting to see something like:

```
he
ll
o
```

However, when i complile, I get:

```
hello
llo
o
```

I do not understand how is `one` and `two`contains more character than the size itself, when i do a `sizeof` for the variables, they all turn out to be `2`, just as the size it was initialized.

And if a `cout` like this is done:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    cout << testptr->one[i] << endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

If i go more than `6`, it would be either empty or rubbish.

I know i can use `memcpy` to allocate nicely the amount bytes into the array, but i'm trying to understand how does a fixed size character array, able to store more that what it can hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `reinterpret_cast` the `char[]` to `struct*`, the pointers to `one`, `two` and `three` point to the 0th, 2nd, and 4th character respectively in the input string (with a gap of two since the size of each variable is two, so something like `ptr`, `ptr + 2`, `ptr + 2 + 2`).

```
h e l l o
^   ^   ^
|   |   |
0   2   4
```

Also, a `char*` in C++ is terminated by a NULL character (`'\0'`). Hence, when you print the value of `one`, `two` and `three`, we see all the characters from the beginning until the end is encountered.

Comment: i see, however, i still do not get how is `one` and `two`, still being able to hold more than what it size is. Is there anyway to limit, and just allowing `one` to store `he`, and `two` to store `ll`.

Comment: They are **not** holding more than their size. Since arrays are stored in contiguous memory, accessing out of bounds (more than 2 characters) gives you the next entry in the string. If this was not the case, you'd have got some garbage value. Because what you are trying to do is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: i see, is there anyway i can use `reinterpret_cast`, and when i `cout` `one`, `two` and `three`, i will be able to get the data i want as above, `one` = `he`, `two` = `ll`, and `three` = `o`, technically `three` is already pointing at the last character in the array.

Comment: I think the only option is to print each character till the size is reached. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the cout you can print the each char array values in for loop until their size to achieve your requirement.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct test
{
    char one  [2];
    char two  [2];
    char three[2];
    test()
    {
        cout<<"in test"<<endl;
        memset(&one,NULL,3);
        memset(&two,NULL,3);
        memset(&three,NULL,3);
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<" one   two   three"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            cout<<one[i]<<"  "<<two[i]<<"  "<<three[i]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
   }

};
main()
{
    test  testobj;
    test  *testptr = &testobj;
    char testchar[] = "hello";
    testptr->display();
    testptr = reinterpret_cast<test*>(testchar);
    testptr->display();
    cout << testptr->one << endl;
    cout << testptr->two << endl;
    cout << testptr->three << endl;
}
```

OUtput:

in test
 one   two   three

one   two   three

h  l  o

e  l

hello
llo
o

Comment: but what i need is after the `reinterpret_cast`, i need the variables to just contain what they have, instead of having to the end of the string where the `\0` is, else i will have to revert back to using `memcpy` to get it done.

Comment: It will contain only the 2 bytes copied, its just because of you are printing it directly without byte by byte it will get printed until the NULL termination. So thats the reason i gave the for loop to display the content in each char array.